# How can I prevent reloading of javascript in camel?

Tags: javascript, apache-camel

I am a starter for camel.

I used javascript for validation logic implement in camel xml.

Initially, it takes some time to load javascript when the first event(a file with some records) comes in. This situation is find.
In this case, only the first record is slow because of loading time of javascript and the rest of the records is normally performed.
The problem is that next event(a file) is coming in.
Camel tries to load javascript again. So, it takes loading time to process each file, so the overall performance has been degraded.

I want to modify some logic so that camel can only load it once.

How can I solve this problem?

```
     <unmarshal id="_FileParsing">
            <bindy
                classType="com.openmzn.ktds.dao.volte.input.VoLTEBody"
                locale="korea" type="Fixed"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <to id="_validateParsing" uri="language:javascript:classpath:spring/rules/volte/volte.js"/>
        <multicast id="_FileDistributor" parallelProcessing="false">
            <toD id="_ProcessNRat" uri="direct:NRAT"/>
            <toD id="_ProcessDrop" uri="direct:DROP"/>
        </multicast>
```

Javascript File

```
       var bodyList = exchange.in.getBody(ArrayList.class);
       if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(bodyList)) {
         for (total_count = 0; total_count < bodyList.size(); total_count++) {
              uBody = bodyList[total_count];
              enriched = enrich(uBody);
              result = validate(enriched);
              resultList.add(result);
         ...
       }

       function enrich(uBody) {
         ...
       }

       function validate(enriched) {
         ...
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on `cacheScript=true`, see the docs
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/components/modules/ROOT/pages/language-component.adoc